# Reactjs nested router does not work on refresh

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router

Hello i am using ReactJs as my frontend for my django project. Im encountering this issue because i wish to separate my login page from my main layout. As such i adopted such a hierarchy of components:

## App.js -> [Main.js -> (Layout.js, etc..) , Login.js]

Apologies for my bad illustration above , here is my code:

## App.js

```
class App extends Component {
###some code####
  render() {    

    if (this.state.checking === true ) {
        return <Spin size="large" />
    } else {
      console.log('state = complete load')
        return (
          <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate}{...alertOptions}>
          <Router>
            <Alerts/>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Main}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
          </AlertProvider>
        )

      }
  }
}
```

## Main.js

```
export class Main extends Component {


render() {
        return (
          <Router>
              <LayoutHeader>
              <BaseRouter/>
              </LayoutHeader>
          </Router>
                )
            }
}

export default Main;
```

## Router.js

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
<div>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/hello" exact component={hello} />
        <Route exact path="*" component={() => '404 NOT FOUND'} />
    </Switch>
</div>
);


export default BaseRouter;
```

Upon refreshing the page in `/hello` im greeted with a blank page. I don't understand whats going on here , would someone explain to me? Thank you!

Comment: Probably back-end is trying to serve `/hello` route which is not existing there, only on front-end. I have explained a similar scenario earlier here: [Problem on manual page refresh due to params passed in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648560/problem-on-manual-page-refresh-due-to-params-passed-in-the-url/57648636#57648636). I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello , i would think thats likely the case. It was resolved with a hashrouter. Strange as it worked previously when i didnt do a nested router