# 404 when trying to enter a react app route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nodes

I just deployed my react app build on c-panel. The app includes different routes and everytime I try to get to one of them I get `404 Not found`.
For example if I try to get to `http://example.com/` it will enter the website, and if I'll press on a button which links me  to`http://example.com/articles` it will work. But If I'll try to get `http://example.com/articles` from a link that I shared or just typing this address I'll get `404 Not found`. This is not happening when I'm running the develope mode on localhost.

I changed the homepage url -  `"homepage": "http://example.com",` in package.json and it did not effect.

My app root is wrapped with `<Router>`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Header title="exampletitle" />
          <MobileHeader />
          <Main />
          <BottomNavbar />
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And this is Main.js component which is maneuvered by the routes.

```
function Main(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Registerpage} />
        <Route exact path="/ap" component={Adminpage} />
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/userpanel" component={UserPanelPage} />
        <Route path="/article/:category" component={Articlepage} />
        <Route path="/articlepage/:id" component={ReadArticlePage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone give me a clue how to make those pages load when I enter them directly by their link?

Comment: You have `path="/article/:category"` which is the closest to `articles`. Probably a typo. Or it tries to render the route from the back-end and that's why it is **404**.

Comment: @norbitrial I'm not talking specifically about this route. All the route are doing the same.

Comment: Probably the back-end tries to look for the route, I have explained a similar scenario [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648560/problem-on-manual-page-refresh-due-to-params-passed-in-the-url/57648636#57648636), maybe this helps to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your application is working for all the routes when you navigate using `<Link>` and `history.push` but throwing **404 Not Found** when you type a URL other than http://example.com, say http://example.com/articles, directly in your browser, you need to:

> Teach your server to handle 404s by **redirecting** to the
>   index.html page.

You can do this in one of the following ways:

1. Add a **custom 404 page** which redirects you to index.html.
2. If your hosting solution, c-panel, provides an **error page setting** for the deployment, provide index.html as the error page.
3. Use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) from react-router. Check [HashRouter Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060999/2873538) and [What's HashRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683217/2873538).

Also, check [notes-on-client-side-routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing) and [How to deploy on cPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49939601/2873538).

Comment: Here is how to do it on [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67312778/2873538) and [apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430478/2873538) servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a bit late ,But the best solution is to :
Use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter and also add a 404.html to public folder with this source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"/>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path[0] + "#" + path;
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + path;
    //document.write("Redirecting To: "+url);
    window.location.href=url;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So now, if you visit http://example.com/articles it will automatically redirect to http://example.com/#/articles almost instantly which you won't even notice and render correctly without any 404 error!!!.

Note: This answer is suitable if you are using github, if you are using cpanel use custom 404 page with above source code.