# Reach router - load component with URL

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

I have a simple router which is possible via the @reach/router module

```
<Router>
   <Home path="/" />
   <Resume path="resume" />
</Router>
```

When someone enter the full URL ending in "/resume" I would like the resume component to show up and I thought this happens automatically via @reach/router but does not seem to be the case.

any strategies to making this work?

Comment: It works. Check [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-reach-router-s3d7f?file=/src/index.js). Not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @AjeetShah Yes, it does work locally but after hosting on netlify it does not seem to work.

Comment: Does it show error 404 not found on netlify? If yes, you may need this strategy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the `<Route />` component to do this.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

render (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
  </Router>
);
```

For reference, here are the docs. [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component)

Comment: OP is not using react-router but [@reach/router](https://github.com/reach/router).

Comment: @Justin Yes, I am not using react-router and it does seem to work locally but not after I host it on Netlify