# Routing on github pages doesn't work. How do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Please tell me why when I refresh a page or if I want to manually enter a link address on my site I get a '404 not found' error. The site is located on github pages. What can I do to correct the bug?

Routing is set up.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/event">
           <Link><Main /></Link>
     </Route>
     <Route path="/api/:id">
           <Description />
      </Route>
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Everything works fine on the localhost.

Tried `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`, but then nothing appears at all.

Comment: Does [React-router urls not working when manually typing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538) help?

Comment: [Creating a custom 404 page for your GitHub Pages site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site) should help.

Comment: the first answer didn't help. About the second -- 404.html should be empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

github pages don't work well for single page application but there is hack around it.
add this script to your index.html in public folder

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
    // https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages
    // Copyright (c) 2016 Rafael Pedicini, licensed under the MIT License
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This script checks to see if a redirect is present in the query string
    // and converts it back into the correct url and adds it to the
    // browser's history using window.history.replaceState(...),
    // which won't cause the browser to attempt to load the new url.
    // When the single page app is loaded further down in this file,
    // the correct url will be waiting in the browser's history for
    // the single page app to route accordingly.
    (function (l) {
      if (l.search) {
        var q = {};
        l.search.slice(1).split('&').forEach(function (v) {
          var a = v.split('=');
          q[a[0]] = a.slice(1).join('=').replace(/~and~/g, '&');
        });
        if (q.p !== undefined) {
          window.history.replaceState(null, null,
            l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + (q.p || '') +
            (q.q ? ('?' + q.q) : '') +
            l.hash
          );
        }
      }
    }(window.location))
  </script>
```

and create a custom 404.html in public folder

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
        // https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages
        // Copyright (c) 2016 Rafael Pedicini, licensed under the MIT License
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // This script takes the current url and converts the path and query
        // string into just a query string, and then redirects the browser
        // to the new url with only a query string and hash fragment,
        // e.g. http://www.foo.tld/one/two?a=b&c=d#qwe, becomes
        // http://www.foo.tld/?p=/one/two&q=a=b~and~c=d#qwe
        // Note: this 404.html file must be at least 512 bytes for it to work
        // with Internet Explorer (it is currently > 512 bytes)

        // If you're creating a Project Pages site and NOT using a custom domain,
        // then set segmentCount to 1 (enterprise users may need to set it to > 1).
        // This way the code will only replace the route part of the path, and not
        // the real directory in which the app resides, for example:
        // https://username.github.io/repo-name/one/two?a=b&c=d#qwe becomes
        // https://username.github.io/repo-name/?p=/one/two&q=a=b~and~c=d#qwe
        // Otherwise, leave segmentCount as 0.
        var segmentCount = 0;

        var l = window.location;
        l.replace(
            l.protocol + '//' + l.hostname + (l.port ? ':' + l.port : '') +
            l.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + segmentCount).join('/') + '/?p=/' +
            l.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(segmentCount).join('/').replace(/&/g, '~and~') +
            (l.search ? '&q=' + l.search.slice(1).replace(/&/g, '~and~') : '') +
            l.hash
        );
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

what this does is that we when refresh the page github actually reaches the server for that specific route but since it's SPA the file won't be available so it send the 404.html page which gets the pathname from the file and calls the index.html page and pastes the pathname there.

Comment: Finally.... thank you so much.

Most people will need `var segmentCount = 1;` read the notes carefully.

Comment: That worked for me too, thank you, finally i found the script <3