# How to properly fetch data from a Url?

Tags: reactjs, url, redirect, react-router

I've created a website using create-react-app and react router. I am able to load the website from https://www.example.com/reactapp but I get a 404 error when I try to access a page like https://www.example.com/reactapp/somePage

The website is running on port 8080, https connection is working, inside my package.json I've defined my homepage as: "https://example.net/reactapp". In my BrowserRouter I've defined my basename as "/reactapp" and links are working and loading the pages just fine.

The thing also is that https://example.net/ displays a wordpress website, when I try to access https://www.example.net/reactapp/somePage I get a 404 error from the wordpress website. How can I properly fetch data when calling for a specific page?

Comment: Then thing you need to search for is "push state routing", your web server needs to fall back to index.html for routes you consider to be frontend pages.

Comment: Check this [404 when trying to enter a react app route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect all requests coming to the server to index.html