# React roues not working as expected on production (shared server environment)

Tags: reactjs

Locally I have the following routes in my react app. And those are working:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    title: 'Login',
    scope: 'auth',
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: '/login-admin',
    title: 'Login Admin',
    scope: 'auth',
    component: LoginAdmin,
  },
```

I can navigate both:
localhost:3360/login and localhost:3360/login_admin

However, when I upload files on server (shared hosting, so I upload build folder content manually) and there is no command line support, then those routes are not working.

I can open [www.mypage.com](http://www.mypage.com) and it redirects me to [www.mypage.com/login](http://www.mypage.com/login) (it is desired functionality), however, if I enter directly [www.mypage.com/login](http://www.mypage.com/login) or [www.mypage.com/login_admin](http://www.mypage.com/login_admin) then it says "Not Found".

Sidenote: this app was not developed by me. It was done by another developer and given to me. It works locally, but not on production server.

Comment: Check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538). You need to your server to redirect to "index.html" for 404 errors.

Comment: If you are using hostgator or something similar [this](https://medium.com/dev-genius/deploying-your-react-app-to-hostgator-quick-and-painless-9807cf939532) helped me, specifically the part about the .htaccess file