# "404 Not Found" on React website subfolders

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webserver, website-deployment

I have a website at https://georgi.karapetrov.top/

Source code: https://github.com/GeorgiKarapetrov/georgi.karapetrov.top

**The issue**

The internal links to the different pages work. I can click on the "About" button in the top bar and the about page loads. In addition, I am routed to the URL for the "About" page.

However, the https://georgi.karapetrov.top/about URL does not load when opened directly.

The same is true for the rest. Accessing any "sub-folder" works by clicking a button but returns "404" not found when typing the URL in the address bar.

Unfortunatelly, nothing appears in the NgingX error log, when I try to access a subfolder. I don't know that I can route to sub-directory locations at the NginX level as these sub-folders don't actually exist on website path.

The website is a React App. The relevant code looks like this:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const { PUBLIC_URL } = 'https://georgi.karapetrov.top/';

const About = lazy(() => import('./pages/About'));

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter basename={PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Suspense fallback={<Main />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        //etc
        <Route component={NotFound} status={404} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

It works as intended when developing or serving a production build on local host, with `npx serve -s build`. It does not work when deployed to an NginX server.

How can I approach this issue?

Comment: [404 when trying to enter a react app route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong, the configuration is at the NginX level.

The virtual host config "server" block used to read:

```
server {
        #some config
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        #etc
}
```

Changing it solved the issue:

```
server {
        #some config
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
        #etc
}
```

Now all pages are routed as they should. Non-existing pages are sent to the custom 404 page.

p.s. All the credit is to Ajeet Shah's [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047422/404-when-trying-to-enter-a-react-app-route/62050700#62050700).