# My Url on server (ionos) don't work when i refresh an other page than Home

Tags: reactjs, server

http://www.la-belle-de-ronce.com/

Hello ! I begin with React app. It's my first deployement. I think it's config server bug.. But it's probably me.

```
index.js :

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

package.json :

"homepage": "http://www.la-belle-de-ronce.com",
 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  
  
  App.js : 
  
  import {Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  import MentionsLegales from './pages/MentionsLegales';
  
  function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <ScrollTop/>
    <Navbar/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/mentions-legales" component={MentionsLegales}/>
      <Redirect to ="/"/>
    </Switch>
    <Footer/> 
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMQJS.png)

On local it's work perfectly. I've test with useHistory.. and I've a folder log on server Ionos with .htaccess i can't remove it.

.htaccess

Options +Indexes
RemoveHandler .html
RemoveType .html
AddType text/html .html
Satisfy any
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 212.227.112.228
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /logs"
AuthUserFile /kunden/homepages/9/d784054432/htpasswd
Require user u97361481

Comment: You need to setup a redirection to `index.html` when there is `404` error. See my answer - [404 when trying to enter a React app route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050700/2873538).

Comment: Thank you very very much !  urls work  !